# Creating an Excel report based on template

Tags: c#, epplus

I have an Excel template where the format for table header, data section and table footer are specified. These sections might have images, merged cells, etc.
The cells where data needs to be mapped are named cells.
I tried using the [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) library for generating the report based on the Excel template.
I used the following snippet to copy the range of cells

```
 var worksheet = destExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");
 var sourceRange = sourceExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First().Cells["B6:P11"];
 sourceRange.Copy(worksheet.Cells["A1"]);
```

But this didn't make the column widths equal to the source. I had to set the column width to the source width as

```
var startCol = sourceRange.Start.Column;
var endCol = sourceRange.End.Column;

for (int j = startCol, destCol = 1; j <= endCol; j++, destCol++)
{
   worksheet.Column(destCol).Width = sourceExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First().Column(j).Width;
}
```

I have the following questions:

---

1. Is there a better way to set the column width equal to the source?
2. The copied cells had an image, but it didn't get copy to the new sheet. How to get the image copied?
3. How to identify the named cells in the Excel sheet so that I can set value to the cell from some data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to achieve points 2 and 3 above.
It appears that if the picture is named, it is easy to read it.
So for #2

```
    private static void CopyImage(ExcelPackage sourceExcelPackage, ExcelWorksheet destWorksheet)
    {
        var image = GetImage("Pic01", sourceExcelPackage);
        ExcelPicture pic = destWorksheet.Drawings.AddPicture("Pic01", image.Image);
        pic.From.Column = image.From.Column;
        pic.From.Row = image.From.Row;
        pic.To.Column = image.To.Column;
        pic.To.Row = image.To.Row;
        var destRow = 1;
        var destCol = 1;
        pic.SetPosition(destRow, Pixel2MTU(image.From.RowOff), destCol, Pixel2MTU(image.From.ColumnOff));
        pic.EditAs = eEditAs.TwoCell;
        pic.AdjustPositionAndSize();
    }

    private static ExcelPicture GetImage(string pictureName, ExcelPackage excelFile)
    {
        var sheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
        var pic = sheet.Drawings[pictureName] as ExcelPicture;
        return pic;
    }

    private static int Pixel2MTU(int fromRowOff)
    {
        return fromRowOff / ExcelDrawing.EMU_PER_PIXEL;
    }
```

And for #3

```
var cell = sourceExcelPackage.Workbook.Names?.Where(item => item.Name==headerName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Will return the cell which is named as headerName.